# Disable sorting feature on columns?

Tags: c#, datatable

I am generating a DataTable in C# and I need to disable sorting the columns via code. The code is something like:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow dr;

dt.Columns.Add("File_Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Create_Date");
dt.Columns.Add("Status");

dr = dt.NewRow();

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

How can this be accomplished? I did check for things like `dt.SortMode = <something disabled>` but so far didn't find any SortOrder on the data element.

Comment: Do you mean sorting the data in the DataTable object itself or sorting the data in whatever control is bound to the DataTable?

Comment: @KevenDenen Basically I don't want users clicking the column heading to sort it. I added another line in my code that I missed if that helps understand.

Comment: You need to change the properties of the GridView then, not the DataTable. The GridView data is the thing getting sorted in this case, not the DataTable.

Comment: @KevenDenen I already tried that. "AllowUserToOrderColumns" is False, and clicking it still sorts the data.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more robust example. I tested this in Windows forms application (.NET 4.5, VS 2012)

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("File_Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Create_Date");
        dt.Columns.Add("Status");

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["File_Name"] = "abc.txt";
        dr["Create_Date"] = DateTime.Now;
        dr["Status"] = "Pending";

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["File_Name"] = "xyz.bmp";
        dr["Create_Date"] = DateTime.Now;
        dr["Status"] = "Complete";

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
        }
```

Hope this helps.

:) David

Comment: Is there anyway I can do this without a loop?

Comment: I'm getting syntax errors: `Error 1 Expected ; or = (cannot specify constructor arguments in declaration)`

Comment: Are you still having issues? Usually this exception is mistyped variable declaration. Not sure how to do this without a loop.

Comment: Is the error occuring on the line with the For Loop, or on the line we set SortMode?

Comment: I updated my answer with a more robust example, which I tested.

Answer (score 1):

"AllowUserToOrderColumns" has nothing to do with sorting data, it determines whether or not the user is allowed to rearrange the columns in the grid. You can disable sorting certain grid columns by setting the respective columns' SortMode as such

`myDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable`